# Upgrade to VS 2015 - error when publishing to Azure

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure-web-app-service

I have an asp.net web application deployed in Azure.
I have just migrated from VS 2013 to VS 2015 and have upgraded from framework 4.5 to framework 4.6.1

My application works fine in local, however when I publish it, I have access to the first login account and then get the following error:

An exception occurred while processing your request. Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom error page for the first exception. The request has been terminated.

I have tried to go back to framework 4.6, but that did not change the problem.

Any idea what it could be?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you may have some references(most likely Azure SDK references) that are not set to Copy local = true, and them are not deployed to Azure.

You could set `customErrors = "Off"` in the Web.config and reploy it to azure to get more detail error info.

```
<system.web>
      <customErrors mode="Off" />
```

Azure WebApp also allow us to remote debug it from Visual studio. You could troubleshoot a webApp in Azure following this Azure [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio#remotedebug).